# Updating rows from the values of previous row

Tags: sql, sas

I have dataset where I need to update the values from the previous rows based on test id.

Dataset that I have.

```
 input acct_num test_id amount ;
    DATALINES; 
    55203610 1  10
    55203610 1  78
    55203610 1  34
    55203610 2  40   
    55203610 2  50
    55203610 2  80
    ;
    run;
```

Data that I need .

```
    DATALINES; 
    55203610 1  10
    55203610 1  78
    55203610 1  34
    55203610 2  10   
    55203610 2  78
    55203610 2  34
    ;
    run;
```

So basically the amount field from testid1 has to be updated to amount field of testid2.

Comment: Easy and safe: You can delete all 55203610 rows and then insert them anew as desired with an insert select.

Comment: is the number of rows in 1 the same rows in 2?

Comment: Can you use a group by and return the total or average of I'd n-1?

Comment: @thorsten Kettner - this is one of the example for 1.6M records so can do that

Comment: @jose_bacoy yes they are same throughout the dataset

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean delete all 55203610 rows, but all test #2 rows of course. Sorry. I would assume this to be even much more efficient than trying to update rows, because for an update to happen you'd have to find some technique first on how to match rows (which probably means giving row numbers to both data sets in the first step).

Comment: @Kendle: You comment was probably meant for some other request?

Comment: What is the LOGIC that explains why the 10 moved from the first row to the forth row?  Why didn't it move to the fifth row or the sixth instead?

Comment: If SAS SQL has RANK you can use a CTE with rank, then do a self join on rank=rank+3 . It might be simpler to use an insert into new_table_name and then drop the old table and rename the new one to the old name.

Comment: @Tom Because the grouping has to be done based on test id, since new test id begins with row 4 hence the the value from row 1 (having test id 1)should come to row 4 (testid4)

Comment: But you have not provided any VARIABLE than can be used to match on.

Comment: @Tom 55203610 is an account number and 1 and 2 are the cases linked with , so for an account number the amount from case1 should flow to case 2

Comment: But you have three observations for acct_num 55203610.  How do you know that the 10 replaces the 40 instead of replacing the 50?  Do you have another variable that counts from 1 to 3 ?

Comment: @Tom yes I have transaction key field which is same of the 10 and 40 , 78 and 50 etc

Comment: If you have unique keys then update the data to show that.

Answer (score 0):

Without unique keys you cannot do this.

If there are no other variables then just eliminate the TEST_ID=2 observations and duplicate the TEST_ID=1 observations.

```
data have;
  input acct_num :$10. test_id amount ;
DATALINES; 
55203610 1  10
55203610 1  78
55203610 1  34
55203610 2  40   
55203610 2  50
55203610 2  80
;

data want;
  set have(in=in1 where=(test_id=1))
      have(in=in2 where=(test_id=1))
  ;
  by acct_num;
  if in2 then test_id=2;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    acct_num    test_id    amount

 1     55203610       1         10
 2     55203610       1         78
 3     55203610       1         34
 4     55203610       2         10
 5     55203610       2         78
 6     55203610       2         34
```

Comment: I have close to 1.5M records , with varying rows each for each test_id , I was hoping something can be done using macros and loop

Comment: Macros are just used to generate code. 1.5 million is a pretty small dataset, especially one with only 3 variables. There is nothing in the code I posted that depends on the number of observations per group.  Unless you are implying that the TEST_ID=1 and TEST_ID=2 groups for the same ACCT_NUM are different sizes.  In that case what do you want to do ?